# blur and focusout IE11 modal dialog

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, modal-dialog

I am having difficulties with IE11 and the focusout/blur events. They are not triggered in the modal dialog, while using FF, Chrome, Edge it works. My code that runs is as following:

```
$("#wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1").blur(function () {
            if ($("#wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1").val() === '4') {
                // do something
            }
            else {
                // do something else            } 

        });
```

or

```
$("#wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1").focusout(function () {
            if ($("#wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1").val() === '4') {
               // do something
            }
            else {
               // do something else
            } 

        });
```

why doesn't it work in IE11? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

This is what I get from the browser:

```
<input name="wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1:::shadow" class="ms-long ui-autocomplete-input ms-inputBox" id="wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1:::shadow" type="autocomplete" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" data-select="function(e, ui) { LookupAutoCompleteSelected(ui, 'Risicoklasse1', false, false);}" data-source="LookupField=Title&amp;RowLimit=100&amp;BPASite=http%3a%2f%2fkwaliteit.domain.local" autocapitalize="off" disableautocomplete="" data-scrollheight="300" data-response-value="0" data-view="0c480c15-b54d-47d2-9abb-5601deb5fcb8" data-list="19d1beb4-5f4a-4758-b3b6-4c59e781ed73" data-colback="Title" bpatitle="Risicoklasse Arbo" checkduplicate="false" multivalue="false" data-source-js="{BPACascading: function () { return getBPACascading(':')}, BPAReverseCascading: function () { return getBPAReverseCascading(':')}}" cascading-params=":">

<input name="wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1" id="wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1" type="hidden" value="4">
```

Comment: And what is `#wTextBoxAutoComplete_Risicoklasse1`? Any plugin you use?

Comment: It is an input field, and when I don't have it as modal dialog the code runs.

Comment: What do you mean by modal? Are you using a plugin to set this 'modal' or is it a default javascript modal as e.g alert, prompt or confirm?!

Comment: Hi, it is called with the OpenPopUpPageWithTitle(url, callback, width, height, title).